# Sound string declaration hangs Arduino compiler

Tags: c, string, audio, arduino, wav

I have a string of characters from an 8 but the [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file that I'm trying to import into my Arduino project. I declare it like this

```
const unsigned char sounddata_data[] PROGMEM = "€€[fill these brackets in with 6500 other characters]";
```

When  I try to run this code, the compiler doesn't give me any errors. It just hangs and never finishes compiling. I know that it's this line because if I declare this with a shorter string, or with other types of declaration (like putting commas between each char), it works.

Is there a line length limit in the Arduino code that's stopping me?

If I have to just accept this and put commas between every character, is there a good method?

I could always write a simple program to do it, but I have a number of sound files to convert and I want to make it easy and simple to read the code.

### Edit

I ended up just writing the program. It converts each data byte into `int`s delimited by commas. It still bothers me that the old way wouldn't work and this way it will take more time, but at least I have something to fall back on

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *r, *w;
    unsigned char ch;
    r = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    w = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    while (fscanf(r, "%c", &ch) != EOF) {
        fprintf(w, "%d, ", (int)ch);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a line length problem then you can break up strings like this:

```
const unsigned char sounddata_data[] PROGMEM = "€€[fill these brackets "
                                               "in with 6500 "
                                               "other chars]";
```

Comment: I just tried splitting it up.  It's giving me a new error.  
    \u0081 is not a universal character.
Arduino seems to be picky...

Comment: I think only ASCII characters are valid in a string literal.